# Using all with multi argument function

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a function a that takes one argument, and a list b with possible inputs, defined as:

```
let a x1 = x1 == 3
let b = [3, 3]
```

Now I want to test that all values in b returns True as arguments to a, which I can do with the all function:

```
all a b
> True
```

However, can I do something similar if a would take two arguments and b would be a list of tuples where each value in the tuple correspond to each argument?

E.g.:

```
let a x1 x2 = x1 == 3 && x2 == 1
let b = [(3,1), (3,1)]
all a b
```

This returns:

```
<interactive>:1:4:
    Couldn't match expected type `Bool'
           against inferred type `a1 -> Bool'
    In the first argument of `all', namely `a'
    In the expression: all a b
    In the definition of `it': it = all a b
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To turn a function with two arguments into a function expecting one pair, use

```
uncurry :: (r -> s -> t) -> (r, s) -> t
```

So, how about

```
all (uncurry a) b
```

?